# Are holes permanent?

Tags: eq-landmark

Everquest Next Landmark allows players to collect resources similar to Minecraft.  If I go in and dig out a large crater looking for them, will that hole get filled back in automatically?

Say I find tin while digging this hole.  If the server "resets" so the hole is filled back in, will it have the same materials as before (i.e. more tin put back where I found it)?

Do trees act the same way?  If I cut down a forest getting wood, will it regrow itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any change made to the land outside of a claim will eventually undo itself. Holes get filled in, trees and herbs respawn, and so on. Minerals seem to be distributed randomly and/or in a different update pass, so a vein will not respawn along with the ground that used to contain it.

In my test run, terraforming reverted roughly 20 minutes after it began, or roughly 10 minutes after the last change I made.